# Python .split()[] <- brackets?

Tags: python, split

I'm working my way through the [Scrapy tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) and encountered this

```
filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
```

I'm somewhat familiar with .split() but have never seen the

```
[-2]
```

bit, and can't seem to figure out what it does. Anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[-2]` is index notation. Since `split()` returns a list `[-2]` access the second element form the end.

For example:

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'b' , 'c']
>>> lst[0]
'a'
>>> lst[-1]
'c'
```